# In an Angular2, how can you inject different data-services into each component

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

Say you have a standard *TodoList* app.

There is an app component, which "provides" a *TodoStore* service which manages(gets/sets/modifies) all the data.

You create *AppComponent* which "provides" this TodoStore and you inject this into your *TodoListComponent*. Everything works as expected.

Now, the customer, for some reason wants to have TWO *TodoListComponent*, side by side. Because components are meant to be reusable and composable, this is a valid use case.

But how would you provide a different *TodoStore* into the two components? Or is my design fundamentally flawed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your `TodoListComponent` with different components that provide different services.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'todo-list-1',
  providers: [{provide: TodoStore, useFactory: (...) => new TodoStore(...), deps: [...]}],
  template: '<todo-list></todo-list>'
})
class TodoList1Component {}
```

For each different store instance use a different wrapper component.

`...` depend on how your store needs to be created (you didn't provide the details).

Comment: Ah! very smart. I see that in your example, you used a factory for the provider. So if you had two different wrapper components, then am I correct in saying that you don't need a factory?

Comment: I just don't know how you create your different instances. They might need to be initialized with different parameters for example. If they are just created with `new TodoStore()` and all you need is 2 different instances then you can replace the whole `providers: ...` line with just `providers: [TodoStore],`